# CSS Select decimals of price without changing HTML markup or using Javascript

Tags: css, select, decimal, price

Is it possible to do a CSS select on the last part of the string? I want to select the `,95` part. This is just an example, it should work on any price in the same format.

```
<div class="price">€9,95</div>
```

Limitations:

- Don't use JavaScript
- Don't alter the HTML

Is this possible (in 2022)?

Comment: No, it is not. CSS still first and foremost selects _elements_. A few special cases are stuff like `:first-line` or `:first-letter`, but those won't help you much here.